# Why @Autowired(required=false) do not work on @Configuration beans?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, autowired

Let explain with an example:

Having this bean:

```
public class Foo {
    private String name;

    Foo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

And this service:

```
public class FooService {
    private Foo foo;

    FooService(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    Foo getFoo() {
        return this.foo;
    }
}
```

Given the following Spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringContext {
//    @Bean
//    Foo foo() {
//        return new Foo("foo");
//    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired(required = false)
    FooService fooService(Foo foo) {
        if (foo == null) {
            return new FooService(new Foo("foo"));
        }
        return new FooService(foo);
    }
}
```

For completeness here is a simple unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringContext.class})
public class SpringAppTests {
    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    @Test
    public void testGetName() {
        Assert.assertEquals("foo", fooService.getFoo().getName());
    }
}
```

**Then loading the context will throw a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException (Foo).**

Can anyone see anything wrong/missing on this example, or provide me a reason for that?

Thank you! Christian

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the other answers:

The problem is that spring does not take the `required=false` into account when injecting parameters. See [`ConstructorResolver`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/ConstructorResolver.java#L835)

```
return this.beanFactory.resolveDependency(
        new DependencyDescriptor(param, true), beanName, autowiredBeanNames, typeConverter);
```

The second argument is always `true`:

[`public DependencyDescriptor(MethodParameter methodParameter, boolean required)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4a57d4512e82aa05dc7a92a0686a6736ae38bfe7/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/DependencyDescriptor.java#L85)

**EDIT:** Spring uses the `ConstructorResolver` for

- **"real" constuctor injection**

  ```
  @Autowired(required=false) // required=false WILL NOT WORK
  public FooService(Foo foo){
      ...
  }
  ```
- **factory methods**

  ```
  @Bean
  @Autowired(required=false) // required=false WILL NOT WORK
  FooService fooService(Foo foo) {
       if (foo == null) {
           return new FooService(new Foo("foo"));
       }
       return new FooService(foo);
  }
  ```

Thus in both cases the `required` attribute is ignored.

Answer (score 4):

You have your syntax wrong. The `@Autowired(required = false)` would need to be relating to the `Foo`.

For example:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringContext {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private Foo foo;

    @Bean
    FooService fooService() {
        if (foo == null) {
            return new FooService(new Foo("foo"));
        }
        return new FooService(foo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`required=false` does work on `@Configuration` beans, however, the `@Autowired` annotation should be placed along with the constructor argument. This is the correct syntax:

```
@Bean
Test1 test1(@Autowired(required = false) Test2 test2){
    return new Test1(test2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
@Configuration
public class SpringContext {
//    @Bean
//    Foo foo() {
//        return new Foo("foo");
//    }

    @Autowired(required = false)
    Foo foo;

    @Bean    
    FooService fooService() {
        if (this.foo == null) {
            return new FooService(new Foo("foo"));
        }
        return new FooService(this.foo);
    }
}
```